# How do I parse the file name below in Groovy ?

Tags: groovy

The file name is of the form IPCM_$date_$sequenceNumber.tar.gz 
E.g. IPCM_20111012151700_00001.tar.gz
What's the best way to get the sequence number token in groovy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very static way would be

```
txt = 'IPCM_20111012151700_00001.tar.gz'
num = txt[-12..-8]
```

More dynamically

```
txt[txt.lastIndexOf('_')+1..txt.indexOf('.')-1]
```

@Steven: this is your solution but working

```
raw = 'IPCM_20111012151700_00001.tar.gz'
num = (raw =~ /IPCM_[0-9]+_([0-9]+).tar.gz/)
print num[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
raw = 'IPCM_20111012151700_00001.tar.gz'
seq = raw.tokenize('_').last()-'.tar.gz'
```

​Or, if you have a random file extension:

```
​raw = 'IPCM_20111012151700_00011.tar.gz'
seq = raw.tokenize('_').last().tokenize('.').first()
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont have a groovy compiler on me, but try:

```
def seqNum = (raw ~= /IPCM_[0-9+]_([0-9+]).tar.gz/)[0]
```

It is probably a bit wrong, but you should get the gist.
(Use regexp matching)

Comment: running your script at http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ (the "portable" groovy compiler) states `unexpected token: ~ @ line 2, column 12.
   print (raw ~= /IPCM_[0-9+]_([0-9+]).tar.gz/)[0]
` so yes, this is a bit wrong. Your regexp is wrong as well.

Comment: Oh well, guess I'm not that great at writing off code and regex without the right tools readily available. My point was to use regex to match the value rather than the range.
*Edit: wow, i only had the +'s on the wrong side too.

Comment: Your hint war correct, but there have been several errors: wrong code, wrong regexp, wrong index to access result. This could have been misleading to the questioner running into more research to solve his problem. Should not be the goal of an answer at SO.